# Getting Session ID in Streaming SQL for Amazon Kinesis

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I have been able to normalize my data into the following format:

```
|ID | SessionState | PreviousID |
|1  |   OFF        |    -       |
|2  |   ON         |    1       |
|3  |   ON         |    2       |
|4  |   OFF        |    3       |
```

What I am trying to do is add a CycleID to this that would premit the following:

```
|ID | SessionState | PreviousID | CycleID |
|1  |   OFF        |    -       |    -    |
|2  |   ON         |    1       |    1    |
|3  |   ON         |    2       |    1    |
|4  |   OFF        |    3       |    1    |
```

At present I am using a lag function that grabs the previous state and previousID (which I was grabbing before), however, I cannot get it to persist until the state change. I more or less need a window that is from

SessionState = 'OFF-->ON'   to   'ON-->OFF'

Since I am doing this in Kinesis Analytics, any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your case lets you push all the data to the database and then use standard SQL - go for it. But if you have time window semantics and need real time responsiveness, complicated with business logic, you will need a specialized tool like Kafka, Spark or Drools.

Answer (score 0):

There is a related question - [Using Kinesis Analytics to construct real time sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40812666/using-kinesis-analytics-to-construct-real-time-sessions), which suggests several options to solve sessionization problem.

Comment: I appreciate it. However, I am using the Lag function to get it to this point, so I am getting the time differential. I just don't have a way to persist the Cycle ID (I have about 6 lag functions to get the motor on/off state the time, and grouping it by device).

Comment: @RWHertenstein2: when the things get complicated, from my experience, the Kinesis Analytics solution simply doesn't fit...

Comment: I believe you are correct. The problem that were having is requiring a partition and sub partition at the same time. I think this may require standard SQL analytics over and above kinesis.

Comment: If your case lets you push all the data to the database and then use standard SQL - go for it. But if you have time window semantics and need real time responsiveness, complicated with business logic, you will need a specialized tool like Kafka, Spark or Drools.

Comment: if you can please put your comment as an answer, then I can market is the answer. I think your second answer/comment is the most accurate for this question.